# What are the .NET frameworks currently available that help build business applications?

Tags: .net, frameworks

And what are their pros/cons in terms of maturity, community support, ease of development ?...

In my mind, a business application framework should provide :

- ORM integration (possibly relying on existing solutions like NHibernate, the Entity Framework...).
- a validation library.
- UI integration components (ASP .NET and/or Windows Forms and/or WPF...).

Comment: It also will be interesting to see your own answer :)

Comment: Well, I just read about Spring .NET or CSLA .NET but I have had no experience with them. Entity Framework+ASP .NET MVC could be considered too...

Answer (score 3):

[DevExpress .NET Business Application Frameworks](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Frameworks.xml)

- eXpressApp Framework
- eXpress Persistent Objects

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But could you add some insight about your experience with this framework ?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have any with this framework, yet. The CodeRush and Refactoring tool are the dogs danglies so I have no hesitation in pointing you towards this framework. Hopefully in a few weeks I will have some experience. I just need to set my laptop up and then I'll be rocking.

Comment: You can find many reviews of these frameworks (all made by real users) on Visual Studio Gallery:

1. [eXpressAppFramework](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/7ED32FD9-B851-4FFA-BE54-DAD981CC2E6D)

2. [eXpress Persistent Objects](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/5368F94D-162E-43D3-8DF8-B4463F05B65C)
and on the official web site:
http://www.devexpress.com/Home/Comments.xml

Finally, feel free to ask for more feedback in [DevExpress forums](http://community.devexpress.com/forums/) and their fan clubs in social networks.

Answer (score 3):

There are loads of tools. Amoung ORMs I would look at.

- ADO.NET Entity Framework
- BLToolkit
- DataObjects.Net
- NHibernate
- EntitySpaces

I am using DataObjects currently but others are also ok.

For WPF applications, I would recommend 
Microsoft Composite Application Library
with Third party controls. For example,

- Telerik .
- infragistics.
- Devexpress

These three are proved to be ok. For web applications,

- Composite Web Application Block
- LiveUI.NET
- .NET RIA Services
- ASP.NET Dynamic Data
- ASP.NET MVC (if UI is not going to be complex)

Answer (score 1):

- Speaking about ORM, take a look at BlToolkit. It is easy to work with stored procedures using it.
- As for UI, there is DevExpress libraries, that contains a lot of controls for all three technologies you listed. For ASP.NET look at ASP.NET MVC if you haven't.

Answer (score 1):

[CSLA.NET](http://www.lhotka.net/cslanet/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But could you add some insight about your experience with this framework ?